# how to load several related entities but not with all his fields, with include?

Tags: entity-framework, database-performance

I have a method that loads many related entities using include clauses, but this to create a query is too big. I need to load many related entities, but I want to load only the fields that are important to me.

```
public RECEIPT_REMITS GetByIDWithIncludes(string UUID) 
{ 
   return Context.RECEIPT_REMITS.Where(h => h.UUID == UUID) .
   Include(r => r.DEPOSITE) 
  .Include(r => r.PROVIDER) 
  .Include(r => r.RECEIPT_KINDS) 
  .Include(r => r.RECEIPT_REMITS_DETAIL.Select(d => 
    d.RECEIPT_REMITS_SERIES)).FirstOrDefault(); 
}
```

Now the sentence loads the data correctly, but only slowly and also bringing fields that I do not need. How can I do this?

Comment: Not understanding. Just remove the `Include()` for things you don't need.

Comment: thanks for answering.  I need to load all entities at first, i need eager loading, the only problem is this sentence to create an query with many unnecessary fields. i know i can use anonymous object but i need it return the entity RECEIPT_REMITS not an anonymous object. i dont know if i am clear

Comment: It should only query your selected fields. See [here](https://benjii.me/2018/01/expression-projection-magic-entity-framework-core/)

Answer (score 2):

Entities represent data records. Complete data records. This makes them poor choices to be used for other purposes such as models for views. Instead you should adopt view models then map entities to view models either via `.Select()` or using Automapper with it's `.ProjectTo<T>()` method which integrates with EF's `IQueryable` implementation. Even if some of the view models end up being identical to the EF model, they serve separate purposes. An entity should always represent the row it is associated to, so you can't expect to tell EF to return a partially filled entity.

For instance if I have a table ReceiptRemit with 10 columns that I care about, and I also want to include related Deposits, but I only care about the ID and amount from the Deposit table:

Entities:

```
[Table("RECEIPT_REMIT")]
public class ReceiptRemit
{
   [Key]
   public string UUID { get; set; }
   public string Field1 { get; set; }
   public string Field2 { get; set; }
   // etc. etc.
   public virtual ICollection<Demerit> Demerits { get; set; } = new List<Demerit>();
}
[Table("DEMERITE")]
public class Demerit
{
   [Key]
   [Column("DEMERITE_ID")]
   public int DemeritId { get; set; }
   public decimal Amount { get; set; }
   public string Field1 { get; set; }
   public string Field2 { get; set; }
   // etc. etc. to match the table, but stuff I don't care about...
}
```

View Models:

```
[Serializable]
public class ReceiptRemitViewModel
{
   public string UUID { get; set; }
   public string Field1 { get; set; }
   public string Field2 { get ; set; }
   // etc. etc.
   public IEnumerable<DemeritSummaryViewModel> Demerits { get; set; } = new List<DemeritSummaryViewModel>();
}
[Serializable]
public class DemeritSummaryViewModel
{
   public int DemeritId { get; set;}
   public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

Then to read: (`.Select()`)

```
public ReceiptRemitViewModel GetByID(string UUID) 
{ 
   return Context.ReceiptRemits.Where(h => h.UUID == UUID)
      .Select(x => new ReceiptRemitViewModel
      {
         UUID = x.UUID.
         Field1 = x.Field1,
         Field2 = x.Field2,
         Demerits = x.Demerits.Select(d => new DemeritSummaryViewModel
         {
            DemeritId = d.DemeritId,
            Amount = d.Amount
         }).ToList(),
       }.Single();
}
```

Which can be a bit of a pain with several related summary details to load, but this can be simplified by using Automapper. Automapper can figure out most common mapping details by convention or be configured for anything specific that doesn't work. Once set up, the above becomes:

```
return Context.ReceiptRemits.Where(h => h.UUID == UUID)
  .ProjectTo<ReceiptRemitViewModel>()
  .Single();
```

Alternatively for things like bulk operations you can define a different entity definition for the related data and register these alternative entities to a new DbContext definition. It has to be a separate DbContext declaration because a DbContext cannot have 2 entities mapped to the same table. This works well for situations where you might need to load relatively large #s of records to inspect and potentially update only a subset of related entities and fields.

Comment: first at all, very kind for all the time you took.

Comment: first at all, very kind for all the time you took. Very clear everything. After doing the whole process on the model view of receip_remits, I will need to update the database. must I create a receipt_remit object, mark it as updated and send it to update? only that? Thanks for all

Comment: You should not need to change your database - that is the point. Craft the ViewModel as Steve has shown in your GET action which will solve your initial performance issue, then use that viewmodel in your View and POST it back where you can update your entities. A very common pattern. Great answer.

Comment: Yes, just to be clear, a view model class is just a plain old C# class, not a table/entity. They typically live in the project that uses them, not with the domain entities. When you pass a view model back to the controller to do an insert (new) you create a new entity, copy the values across from the view model (Automapper can help there too) and add the entity to the DbSet. When you do an update you load the entity by ID including any children that may be updated, then copy applicable values from the view model. Check over everything in the view model first to ensure the data is valid.

Comment: thank you. and I seem to be writing very badly because they do not let me ask any more questions, haha, I'm going to have to adapt better to this medium. regards